# One method accepting different parameters

Tags: c#, .net

Using `FW 4.5.1` I have a method:

```
void DoSomething(string s)
```

I want to allow the function to accept `int` as well, but under the same parameter s. That means I want to write:

```
void DoSomething(var s)
```

and sometimes `s` will be `int`, sometimes `string`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `void DoSomething(object s)`

Comment: Or just overload it: write `void DoSomething(int x)` as well as `void DoSomething(string s)`. This is more appropriate if you *only* want it to handle `int` and` string`. Or you could use generics.

Comment: Why do you want to allow `int` **and** `string`? Is the `string`-overload just doing a simple `int.Parse`?

Comment: [`var` does not mean that the type can be anything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx); it means that the variable has exactly *one* type, and that type is inferred by the compiler from context at compile time instead of being explicitly stated by the programmer. That's relatively easy (for certain values of "easy") with a variable that is declared once; for functions, they gave us generics instead.

Comment: @EdPlunkett don't you forget about [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741), [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject), ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes, those features exist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Three options for you to consider, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve:

### Use overloads

```
public void DoSomething(int s) { ... }
public void DoSomething(string s) { ... }
```

This will *only* accept `int` and `string` - which could be a good or a bad thing, depending on what you're trying to achieve. If you really only want to be able to accept `int` and `string`, this is the best solution IMO.

### Use `object`

```
public void DoSomething(object s) { ... }
```

This will allow you to pass in anything.

### Use generics

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value) { ... }
```

This will still allow you to pass in anything, but will provide a bit more type safety if (say) you want to later accept *two* values which have to be the same type (or at least compatible types)

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve what you want with overloads.

```
void DoSomething(string s){ DoSomething(int.Parse(s)); }
void DoSomething(int s){ /* Your code here */ }
```

Or the other way around:

```
void DoSomething(string s){ /* Your code here */ }
void DoSomething(int s){ DoSomething(s.ToString()); }
```

Comment: [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): is the class really responsible for dealing with "broken" input parameters, or is it the callers responsibility to provide a valid input?

Comment: The idea is to provide backwards compatibility, so it need to be smooth for the 100 places in the code that call this function.

Comment: @Itay.B Thanks for the clarification - yet, I suggest to follow the [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) to get rid of the extended class later on (which *should* be the ultimate target of your refactoring mission) - nevertheless, this issue is out of your question's scope :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use generics

```
void MyMethod<T>(T param)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        // the object is an int
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        // the object is a string
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was aiming for. Checking it right now. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't feel terribly "generic" to me, as it only really handles two types - if only two types are meant to be supported, I'd use overloads instead.

Comment: I would just create two different methods here, no point in using generics if the code you are performing on them will be different

Comment: Agreed @JonSkeet I was sure the OP wanted one method only but couldnt suggest a better implementation without the actual method OP wants to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Overloads is the right answer 99.9999% of the time, but for the hell of it here's another answer.  This is slightly better than using `object` because it will cause a compile-time error if the caller does not supply a value type.

```
static void DoSomething(IConvertible input)
{
    if (input is int)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if (input is string)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    //etc....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that generics was what you was after (quoting the code here for reference):

> ```
> void MyMethod<T>(T param)
> {
>     if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
>     {
>         // the object is an int
>     }
>     else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
>     {
>         // the object is a string
>     }
> }
> ```

However, this isn't very generic and is actually doing two different actions depending on the type. This tells me you probably just want two different methods:

```
void DoSomethingWithString(string s)

void DoSomethingWithInt(int n)
```

If the code would be similar inside though use method overloading as @juunas suggested or use `object` as @Jon Skeet suggested.

If you have a lot of common code use method overloading to convert to an acceptable format and then call a common method. Obviously if the common format is `string` or `int` then just use method overloading.

```
void DoSomethingCommon(/*SomeCommonThing*/ thing)
```

Comment: But then ill have to duplicate the content of the methods? 60 lines of code.

Comment: @Itay.B Then either use a common method after converting to a common type or use one of the answers already suggested